# return the part of string by specifying first and last position in php

Tags: php, string

How can I return a part of string by specifying the first and last positions in php? i couldn't find any function related to it.

For example :

```
<?php 
   $string1 = "A test string";

// output required is "test" but with specifying integer positions 
// start = 2
// end = 5

?>
```

It can be done with `substr($string1,2,4);`
But if i dont know the length, i would want a function which takes first position and last position.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just calculate the length as `end-start+1`?

Comment: Why not run a loop and get the value of string if there is not function that does this task?

Comment: @klaus thanks that gives me the missing length .

Comment: Was it really a bad question that i got downvotes to it ????? I just wanted to know if there is any function available in php .

Comment: @Sitepose I believe people downvoted because it was too easy. It's just a matter of math to calculate it. But then again, I don't know, I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the length like **end-start+1**

```
substr($string1,$start,$end-$start+1)
```

Like

```
<?php 
   $string1 = "A test string";
   $start = 2
   $end = 5

   // if you know the length
   $str1 = substr($string1,$start,4);

   // if you don't know the length
   $str2 = substr($string1,$start,$end-$start+1);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a two step method to first strip off the characters to the start, the get the characters to the end.

```
$string1 = "A test string";
$start = 2;
$end = 5;


$str = substr($string1, $start); //"test string";
$str = substr($str, 0, $end); //"test";

echo $str; //test
```

https://3v4l.org/aO9e7

---

The closest function I know that is what you are looking for is for arrays and is called array_slice/array_splice.

But that means you need to make the string array, slice it and join back to string.

```
$string1 = "A test string";
$start = 2;
$end = 5;

$arr = str_split($string1);

$wordarr = array_splice($arr, $start, $end);

echo implode("", $wordarr); // test
```

This is not a recommended method.